# how to extract portion of a string between two substrings in a multiline string in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract the portion of a string between two string identifiers. The technique works if the search is made in first line but it do not work for substrings in other line.

The string is like this:

```
mystring="""abc jhfshf iztzrtzoi hjge);
kjsyh ldjfsj sjsdgj sodfsd);
sjfhsdvh isdjgdfg sdgjhg isjdgg);
ghdcbnv jgdfkjg fdjgjfdgj);
vgdfnkvgfd dfgjfdjgjöfd);
end"""
```

Until now I have the following code.

```
startString='jhfshf'
endString=';'
search_var=mystring[mystring.find(startString)+len(startString):mystring.find(endString)]
print(search_var)
```

I get the correct output like `iztzrtzoi hjge)`

But if I search for a string in second line like `(startString=ldjfsj)`, it do not work. Can can body suggest some changes for correction?

Comment: `mystring.split('jhfshf')[1].split(';')[0]` (you could add maxsplits to improve efficiency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Demo:**

```
import re
mystring="""abc jhfshf iztzrtzoi hjge);
kjsyh ldjfsj sjsdgj sodfsd);
sjfhsdvh isdjgdfg sdgjhg isjdgg);
ghdcbnv jgdfkjg fdjgjfdgj);
vgdfnkvgfd dfgjfdjgjöfd);
end"""

m = re.search("(?<=jhfshf).*?(?=\;)", mystring)
if m:
    print( m.group() )
```

**Output:**

```
 iztzrtzoi hjge)
```